# Problem with 14.04 on Mid-2011 Macbook Pro 17

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, screen, macbook

I am trying to install Trusty on a 2011 Macbook Pro 17 with a broken Nvidia card.  I have booted it successfully and installed the OS from a USB stick using nomodeset, but now I cannot get the installed system to work. It boots to a black screen and hangs with a compatibility error. I tried booting with F6 and changing the grub settings, but it hangs on a purple screen.
Can anyone tell me exactly text what I need to set in grub to get it to bypass the Nvidia drivers like it did on the USB bootup?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I got a GRUB boot instruction from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157775), but I can't test it. I don't think GRUB can resolve that, but there's no harm in trying:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.lvds_channel_mode=2 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0"`

You could also disable the GPU in the EFI. This thread should be helpful:
https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/force-2011-macbook-pro-8-2-with-failed-amd-gpu-to-always-use-intel-integrated-gpu-efi-variable-fix.2037591/

EDIT: there's apparently a [GRUB patch](https://sasanj.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/how-to-turn-off-apple-macbook-pro-discrete-graphics-card-for-linux/) for this particular case

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.The GRUB_CMDLINE option did not help (or I did it wrong).
The other two solutions look too complicated for me.
I did manage to get the system to boot in 'Safe' mode and it works well, now I need to tackle setting the options permanently.
Thanks for the help; I will get back to you after I try implementing a permanent solution.